# Django - test multiple views at once

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-testing

Can I test multiple views against one condition? For example if all of these views uses `LoginRequiredMixin` or `@login_required` decorator?

This is just for one url which calls `IndexView`.

```
class IndexTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(username='testuser')

    def test_login_required(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("profiles:user_filter"))
        self.assertRedirects(response,reverse("account_login")+"?next={}".format(reverse("profiles:user_filter")))
```

I would like to test if all views except one or two has `LoginRequiredMixin` so if I create new view in future, tests will fail if I forgot to use `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Answer (score 2):

Two parts to this answer:

1. Python unittests are pretty explicit. To test multiple views, you need to make multiple requests. One request per view. You could put the reverse names in a list and loop through them and do an assert for each in the loop.
2. You shouldn't test more than one individual view at a time. They are called unittests for a reason. You're testing an individual unit for an individual behavior. I would set it up where each view has its own `TestCase` class. Then, for each of those test cases, test that that individual view redirects if not logged in. So you'll end up having a `TestCase` with a test method for each view. Therefore, you'll have one or more test methods that tests login validation for each view.

The philosophy behind unittests is that each test should only test a tiny chunk of behavior. To ensure you're doing this, you should only have 1 assertion per test method. Only in extreme cases should you have more than one, and if so, they should all be very connected to each other logically.

---

If you want to know what views don't have the `login_required`/`LoginRequiredMixin` implementation, I don't think there's anything that can help you in that beyond searching via the editor's search engine. I could be wrong so I'm not saying this for certain, but I think you're just gonna have to use file search.

You could write a script that looks through all url.py files and loops through every url:

```
for url in app1.urls.urlpatterns: # loop through urls in "urlpatterns = [url(...), url(...), ...]"
    url_name = <get_url_name_from_pattern>
    response = # request to url without login
    if response.status_code = 302: print "this view has login required"
    else: print "this view doesn't have login required"

for url in app2.urls.urlpatterns: # loop through urls in "urlpatterns = [url(...), url(...), ...]"
    url_name = <get_url_name_from_pattern>
    response = # request to url without login
    if response.status_code = 302: print "this view has login required"
    else: print "this view doesn't have login required"

for url in app3.urls.urlpatterns: ...
```

You'll have to look up how to get the reverse name for a urlpattern. I've never done that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that unittests are not the way. What I want is: Something (module, test or ...) which tells me, if there are some views (except listed) in my project which don't extends LoginRequiredMixin so I don't have to check the every view one by one.